# Char array with cin.getline()

Tags: c++

I'm doing an assignment where we aren't allowed to use strings, we have to use char arrays. This is my code:

```
cout << "Enter Album name: ";
cin >> CDdata[count].title;     
fout << CDdata[count].title;
```

the problem is that when I enter something with a space in it, the rest of my code gets screwed up.

How do I get it so that I can enter something with a space in it?

Comment: What do you mean by "the rest of my code gets screwed up". Please describe the specific problem you are having, and post the other code that is affected if appropriate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `cin.getline(CDdata[count].title, 1000)`. The second parameter is the length of your char array, `CData[count].title`.

The above function either reads 1000 characters or until it finds a delimiter, which is by default a newline (`\n`) but can be changed as follows.

```
 cin.getline(CDdata[count].title, 1000, ',') //delimiter is changed to ','
```

If you want a more formal description, read [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/getline/).

**P.S:** I have used 1000, second argument, as a placeholder. You should change it accordingly.

Comment: When I do this: cin.getline(CDdata[count].title, 1000) it doesn't let me enter anything and just skips to the next line of code.

Comment: There's a probably a newline in buffer left from some previous `cin`. You can do `cin.ignore()` before `cin.getline()` which will remove it from the stream.

Comment: how can I handle the error if the user type more chars than the specified length?

Comment: @alibttb use `std::getline(cin, a_std_string)` instead of `cin.getline(a_char_buffer, length)`

Answer (score 1):

Use [`cin.getline()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/getline/) as it will `'\n'` as the terminating character and not space.

Comment: Haha.. You beat me to it by 4 seconds! :D

Comment: I have done this: cin.getline(CDdata[count].title) but I get this error: 
error: no matching function for call to 'std::basic_istream<char>::getline(char [256])'

Comment: @vidit You should undelete your answer. You provided a complete example of how to call the function (including the `count` parameter); you could even add a few words about the importance of the buffer size etc. Stackoverflow isn't about fast answers, but good ones.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

when cin.getline() is escaping some thing its bc of some previous data in buffer that we can clean by cin.ignore() it escape the first caracter while reading from buffer